# How to POST Directly From One Website to Another Within the Same Server

Tags: http, redirect, post, networking

Sorry, if this is a duplicate, because I really didn't know what keywords I should look for. The couple I've tried on Google returned results that are not relevant to the questions I have in mind.

I've one Linux server that hosts two websites (e.g. sites ABC.com and XYZ.com) which are all bound to the same IP address. The domain names are not listed in /etc/hosts.

If site ABC.com has a web form that sends some content via POST method to XYZ.com, my question is:

1. Does the POST data make a trip out of the server, through the various relays before coming back to the same server?

Or

2. Is the web server or operating system smart enough to know that the destination is itself and therefore send the POST data directly without making a big round trip?

If it's (1), how can I change it to (2)? Does putting the domain names in /etc/hosts help? Like this:

```
127.0.0.1    ABC.com
127.0.0.1    XYZ.com
```

Any unintended side effects for configuring /etc/hosts in this way?

Is there a way to verify that (2) is indeed happening on the server after implementing your proposed solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it like this:

**Form_on_abc.com.html**

```
<from action="xyz.com/postit" method="POST">
```

the submitted data will *never* be send to abc.com. The browser (running on some client computer on the outside) would send the data directly to xyz.com.

If on the other hand it looked like this:

**Form_on_abc.com.html**

```
<from action="abc.com/forward_to_xyz" method="POST">
```

And you'd have some server-side-code to redirect the post to xyz.com internally, then your data might stay on the server. But that would depend on how you do the redirection, if your IPs are in the same subnet and so on.